# is there a way to make selenium click this next button until it's unclickable using the class name instead of the id

Tags: python, html, selenium

This is the button that i want to click

```
<a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">Next</a>
```

until it becomes this

```
<a class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">Next</a>
```

the XPATH for the button is

```
//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_next"]
```

Currently, i am doing this, dataTables shows Page 1 of 10, 2 of 10 and so on so i made a python function to stop when it becomes 10 of 10. This is the html code.

```
<div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Page 1 of 10</div>
```

then it will click the next tab. this is my python code.

```
entries = driver.find_element_by_class_name('dataTables_info').text
entries = entries.replace(',', '')
check = [int(s) for s in entries.split() if s.isnumeric()]

if check[0]!=check[1]:
    driver.find_element_by_id('DataTables_Table_0_next').click()
```

and my code works. but the thing is on the next page, it becomes DataTables_Table_1 and DataTables_Table_1_next.

I have tried to do this

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('paginate_button next').click()
```

but it doesnt seem work. it just stays on the same page over and over.

Does anyone have a way around this? A way to click the next button using the class name instead of the id so i can apply it to every table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the class of the Next button as follows.
Then you can use while clause by checking the class of the button every after clicking the  element.
If the class contains 'disable', you will just break the while.

```
xpath = "//a[contains(@class,'paginate_button next')]"
while(True):
    # <- Put here the code snippet for getting the data for the page
    cls = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute("class")
    if 'disabled' not in cls:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: //*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_next"] is the XPATH, would that work? on the next page it would be //*[@id="DataTables_Table_1_next"].

Comment: That id seems like to change for me. Use class attribute for more robust solution. I am editing the answer right now.

Comment: your previous code worked but now im getting AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' for some reason, im trying to troubleshoot now

Comment: Sorry, there was an error. Try again with the edited answer

Comment: Actually you need to check if the contents are reloaded. If the page reloads, we would need to give some break after clicking the element.

Comment: it works properly, but i think cause of the way the while loop is done, i cant get the values on the last page. also is it possible to add a presence_of_all_elements_located so it waits for the page to load or something?

Comment: okay i fixed the while loop, but now when i go to the next tab i get this error 
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=76.0.3809.132) i think because it stays on the last page in the next tab, is there a way to make it go back to page one like a reload?

Comment: I edited the code so that you can get contents from the last page too. About the next question, I don't understand well. Is it possible to share the URL? I guess there can be a better way just using the URL.

Comment: it mostly works but is there a way to add a reload because when i click the next tab it still on the last page, it doesnt go back to the first page. thanks for all your help  btw

Comment: <when i click the next tab it still on the last page, it doesnt go back to the first page> I really don't understand this. what do you mean by last and first here?